# How can I square a number in Perl?

Tags: perl, loops

I have code to print out the first 9 squared numbers:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

for($i=1;$i<10 ;$i++ )
{
   printf $i^2 . "\n";
}
```

but for some reason this just outputs 30167451011. How do I properly square a number?

Comment: as oneliner: `perl -E 'say $_**2 for(1..9)'`

Comment: I am glad you got an answer to your question, but reading the docs is a virtue: `perldoc perlop`, `perldoc perltoc`.

Comment: also `$i * $i`    __________

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[To square you have to use $i**2](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Exponentiation)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

for ( my $i = 1; $i < 10; $i++ ) {
    print $i**2 . "\n";
}
```

This will output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Answer (score 8):

To explain what happened in the original code, you need to know 3 things: first, `^` is the XOR operator in perl, because it is the XOR operator in C.

```
1 ^ 2 = 3
2 ^ 2 = 0
3 ^ 2 = 1
4 ^ 2 = 6
...
```

Second, the `^` operator has lower precedence than the string concatenation operator `.` so `$i^2 . "\n"` is equivalent to `$i ^ (2 . "\n")`

Third, perl converts between strings and numbers as necessary. The `.` operator requires strings on both sides, so the `2` is converted to `"2"` and concatenated with the `"\n"` to become the string `"2\n"`.

Then the `^` operator requires numbers on both sides, so the string `"2\n"` is converted to a number - by taking the leading number-looking portion and throwing away the rest. So the result of `$i ^ 2 . "\n"` is ultimately the same as `$i ^ 2`. Your `"\n"` didn't have any effect at all, so all the results are printed with nothing between them. `3`, `0`, `1`, `6`, ... became `3016`...

Answer (score 4):

`^` is the [Bitwise Xor operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Bitwise-Or-and-Exclusive-Or)

To square a number, you want the [Exponentiation operator `**`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Exponentiation)

```
for my $i ( 1 .. 9 ) {
    print $i**2, "\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach my $i (1..9){
   say $i**2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieve by doing this way also:

```
for (1..9) {
   print $_*$_,"\n"
}
```

Output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to get the squares.

```
print $_**2,"\n" for 1..10;
```